# Trouble filtering with where-object

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I can't seem to figure out why this where object filter is not working.
here is the code:

```
Get-MailDetailTransportRuleReport -StartDate 08/25/2022 -EndDate 09/07/2022 
| Where-Object -Property SenderAddress -NotContains "@EMAIL-DOMAIN-HERE" 
| fl Date, Subject, Direction, SenderAddress, RecipientAddress, TransportRule
```

and I am of course, getting all of the results with the "@EMAIL-DOMAIN-HERE" still in it.

Answer (score 4):

`-notcontains` is a [*collection containment* operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators), not a string comparison operator.

Use `-notlike` instead and make sure you include appropriate wildcards:

```
| Where-Object -Property SenderAddress -NotLike "*@EMAIL-DOMAIN-HERE"
```